# Flash message don't show up when I do return redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a weird problem(I'm still learning rails) with rails and flash messages.

I have a link_to with method post in my rails view:

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>".html_safe, email_post_path(@post.id), method: 'post' %>
```

and in my controller I do this:

```
def email_post
  # do nothing
  return redirect_to posts_path, alert: 'test flash'
end
```

The problem 
is that works fine(so it redirect me correctly), but don't show the flash message(and the problem is not about the showing flash message, but that the flash[:alert] doesn't exists)

This is the way I show the flash messages:

```
<%= binding.pry %> #used for see if the flash is empty or not - and in this case is it!
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="flash-<%= type %>">
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Why don't show the flash message in this case ?

Comment: if I remove the return then it give me a error about "DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action." why ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem seems to be

```
error: 'lol'
```

With:

```
alert: 'lol'
```

Works fine...why ?